# How to calculate as array element +1

Tags: javascript

The expression in the following conditional statement is not working as expected. The items in the array are "string" type.

```js
if(parseInt(array.length)+1 % 7 == 0) {
  //...
}
```

How can I correct the expression?

Comment: The question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve and what is wrong with your current code ?

Comment: Sorry. The purpose is to +1 the number of elements in the array.

Comment: `%` has a higher precendence than `+`. Please check the [order of precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) table in the documentation. And add `()` if your unsure of the order to make it clear to other people reading the code

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((array.length + 1) % 7 == 0)
```

should do the job. `array.length` is of type Number already, so no need to parse it.

Without the parenthesis around `(array.length + 1)` the modulo operator `%` is applied to the 1 only, messing up the condition.